# PHP Carbon set timezone offset adds hours

Tags: php, date, time, php-carbon

I have a carbon object **`new Carbon`** and then call `->setTimezone()` method  on it. 
When I call the method with the value of a timezone string such as `Europe/London`, I can call the method as many times as I want with no issue. 
However if I call it with the value of `+02:00`, every time the method is called it adds 2 hours to the time. It only happens for none type 3 time zones. 
**Why does this happen and how can I fix it?**

Code showing problem:

```
$c = new Carbon()

=> Carbon\Carbon {#1942
     +"date": "2018-01-04 14:21:57.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }

$c->setTimezone('+02:00')->setTimezone('+02:00')->setTimezone('UTC')

=> Carbon\Carbon {#1942
     +"date": "2018-01-04 18:21:57.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
```

Comment: Do you have code to reproduce it?

Comment: Added code example to reproduce problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in PHP (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72338) that was fixed in PHP 7 (7.0.17 and 7.1.3).

If you're stuck on an earlier version there's a workaround mentioned in the comments to the bug report, namely calling `getTimestamp()` between `setTimezone()` methods.

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$plus200 = new DateTimeZone('+02:00');

$date = new DateTime('2018-06-14 09:15:00', $utc);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2018-06-14 09:15:00

$date->setTimezone($plus200);
$date->setTimezone($plus200);
$date->setTimezone($utc);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2018-06-14 13:15:00

$date = new DateTime('2018-06-14 09:15:00', $utc);

$date->getTimestamp();
$date->setTimezone($plus200);
$date->getTimestamp();
$date->setTimezone($plus200);
$date->getTimestamp();
$date->setTimezone($utc);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2018-06-14 09:15:00
```

Test script with output from various versions: https://3v4l.org/cXZYC